# Android Studio 0.8.2 Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bit Cannot Resolve Symbol all android classes

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I just built a new laptop and changed from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04. I'm running AS 0.8.2 on both machines (old and new). When trying to pick up development on the new machine AS shows Cannot Resolve Symbol  errors on all android classes. It builds just fine either through the IDE or through gradle on the command line. But the code completion in the editor shows red all over.

I have the min sdk and the target sdk installed through the SDK Manager. I've built it with gradle 1.10 and gradle 1.12. I have tried backing off the build tools version to 19.1 with no effect. As far as I can see the only difference is that this setup is on 14.04.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

android {
     signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig {
            <stuff here>
        }
        debugConfig {
            <stuff here>
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.domain'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 0
        versionName '0.1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            zipAlign true
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugConfig
            zipAlign true
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        freeFlavor {
            applicationId 'com.domain.lite'
        }
        paidFlavor {
            applicationId 'com.domain.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
}
```

Any thoughts, or anyone else running into this?

**EDIT**

Interesting. If I copy the android.jar from the sdk into the project's libs directory AS recognizes things just fine. So it's not recognizing the sdk location of its contents. I've checked in the project structure and it is correctly set to /usr/android-studio/sdk

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project. You shouldn't work with android.jar in your libs folder. Also compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+' requires android-L. Use compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+' or 20.+

Comment: Thanks @GabrieleMariotti I must have updated that inadvertently. I've since pulled it back to 19+

Also, I've found that it is only API 19 that is causing the problem. If I change the compileSdkVersion to something else it seems to work. The other strange thing is that if I declare an sdk level that I do not have installed it asks if I want to install it and update, then presents a dialog to do so. However, if I remove 19 and try to do the same thing it prompts me to launch the sdk manager to install 19. 

So what's so strange about 19?

Comment: Looks like this is an issue using the Sync Project with Gradle button. Others see it also and modifying the .iml file will temporarily correct it. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73445